# How can we use SVM model in SQL SERVER 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL Server 2016 R services,

I searched several documents and links on web but i failed to get complete details on svm in SQL Server 2016, please help to learn

Comment: does this help :https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2017/01/05/how-six-lines-of-code-sql-server-can-bring-deep-learning-to-any-app/

Comment: Hi! So what do you want to do, and what are you asking? In later releases of MicrosoftR you have rxOneClassSvm, as well as rxFastLinear. For both of these you probably need to update the R version in SQL Server 2016 to the latest version.

Comment: Thank you for responding @TheGameiswar and @ Niels, I had installed "cummulative update 4" in my server system, But I am getting error like "Error: could not find function rxOneClassSvm". Is there any methods to know the version of SQL Server 2016 to get conformation i had updated SQL Server 2016 properly. Is there any other reason for the above error

Comment: Hi @Niels, Can we get the details of installed packages in SQL Server 2016 R Services

Answer (score 0):

Hey V L SUDHAKAR INAMPUDI,

OK, so `rxOneClassSvm` is part of MicrosoftML, which ships with the Microsoft R Server version 3.3.2. The version of Microsoft R Server in SQL Server 2016 R Services is 3.2.2. Installing CU4 will not update the R version. To see what version you have, you can run following R code in your SQL Server:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'R' ,
@script = N'print(R.Version()$version)'
```

You can update the existing version to a later version, but there are some minimum requirements of what service packs etc., you have installed for SQL Server. However, having CU4, you should be golden. This link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoftrservertigerteam/2017/03/22/running-microsoftml-in-sql-server/ should give you information how to upgrade the R version.

If you want to see what packages you have installed you can run following code:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N'R'
    , @script = N'
    OutputDataSet <- data.frame(installed.packages()[,c("Package", "Version", "Depends", 
"License", "Built", "LibPath")]);'
WITH RESULT SETS ((Package nvarchar(255), Version nvarchar(100), 
                   Depends nvarchar(4000), License nvarchar(1000), 
                   Built nvarchar(100), LibPath nvarchar(2000)));
```

Hope this helps!